# graph databases and Eulerian path

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I am studying graph databases (Neo4J).
I know graph databases come from graph theory, which has basis on Euler paper to solve the 7 bridges problem.. eulerian path/eulerian circuit.

I am trying to find an example, something, to show how graph databases use the Eulerian path to solve some problem.
Ideally I would need a real example from a source, but even any help to understand this better.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a misimpression. Even though Euler wrote a paper based on the 7 bridges problem (which was probably the first paper on graph theory), that does not mean that the design of neo4j uses his solution to that specific problem in any way.

Comment: thanks cybersam, I am not thinking that Neo4j uses Euler in his design. I was trying to understand if the Euler problem can be applied to any current problem and solved with graph databases. I have seen a paper where different algorithms (dikastra, travelling salesman etc) are solved using graph databases and benchmarks done.. thank you!